# How to disable Windows 11 pin?

Tags: windows-11

I don't want to type a PIN number (`****`) each time I log into Windows 11.

I went through the options but didn't find a way to cancel or disable this PIN requirement.

How to disable Windows 11 pin?

On this particular computer I also don't want a password/fingerprint/facial recognition.

Comment: There should be an icon to switch to entering a password instead of a pin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 11 PIN is tied to Fingerprint / Facial recognition.

If you have the above AND if you do not have a regular password, then you cannot disable PIN.

If you have a regular password, then you can go into Account Settings and remove PIN and Fingerprint / Face.

I do NOT recommend the latter approach.

You can additionally go to Settings, Accounts, Sign In options and then in that section, near the bottom, you can UNCHECK the option to only allow Windows Hello.

Once unchecked, you will see sign in options and can use the option you like.

You MUST have a password to disable PIN. That is how Windows 11 works. Once you have password only, you can try to eliminate the password .

My own view is that we should always have at least a password to achieve the most basic security.

Comment: I don't want anything like fingerprint/FR/password/PIN I just want to login without any of these...

Comment: You MUST have a password to disable PIN. That is how Windows 11 works. Once password only, you can try to eliminate the password but that is a remarkably terrible idea.

Comment: Thank you John, I think your last comment should be edited into your answer is it answers the question in its updated version.